# How to use Adjacent sibling selectors in css

Tags: html, css

here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="main">
    <h1>
        <div class="details-of-family-members">Details of Family Members</div>
    </h1>
    <div class="wrap data">
        <h1> Hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS to hide `.wrap.data` *div* based on *div* of class `.details-of-family-members` which is inside *h1*.

Comment: You can't style `.wrap.data` based on `.details-of-family-members` using pure CSS. They don't have a parent-child relation or a sibling relation.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 there isn't a option to select the parent based on the child.

We got this sittuation: `h1` is sibling of `.wrap.data`, not `details-of-family-members`.

Therefore, you should add the class `details-of-family-members` to `h1` tag. And then you can:

```
.details-of-family-members + .wrap.data {
    display:none;
}
```

```css
.details-of-family-members + .wrap.data{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <h1  class="details-of-family-members">
        <div>Details of Family Members</div>
    </h1>
    <div class="wrap data">
        <h1> Hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the whole code in the answer, check both HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you cannot target parent node based on child by css

```
#main h1:hover + .wrap.data {display:none;}
```